Size of the pusdown stack of NPDA
Assume that a (nondeterministic) pushdown automaton $A$ is given. Given a word $w \in L(A)$, one would like to know how a derivation of $w$ in $A$ might look like. One way to formalise this question is, for any derivation of $w$ by means of $A$, to consider how the size of the pushdown stack changes when reading $w$, namely, to draw a graph of the function $f(i)$ where $i$ is the position in $w$ ($i=1,\dotsc,|w|$) and $f(i)$ equals the length of the pushdown stack in a fixed derivation of $w$ after reading the first $i$ symbols. For example, in the standard pushdown automaton generating $\{a^nb^n\}$, the graph of such a function $f(i)$ constructed from the derivation of $a^nb^n$ would look like a triangle; namely, $f(i)=i$ for $i\le n$ and $f(i)=2n-i$ for $n < i \le 2n$.
I wonder if such functions and graphs associated with derivations in a PDA have been studied in the literature on pushdown automata. I would be interested in any relevant references. In particular, I look for context-free languages with "weird" behaviour of these graphs (I understand that this is informal).
